# Создание объекта и ключевое слово new

Tags: java

Не очень понимаю суть этой конструкции: new НазваниеКласса

```
JButton b2 = new JButton("Click");
b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Кнопка нажата!");
    }
});
```

В данном примере не понимаю как выполняется код new ActionListener().
Вот сделал пример:

```
public class Test {
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Я бегу");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().run();
    }
}
```

Получается у нас либо всегда будет писать new Test().run();
Либо мы присвоим конструкции new Test() ссылку, чтобы мы могли её использовать и вызывать метод run(), я правильно понял?

Comment: `new Test.run()` - так делается, когда объект используется только один раз для вызова только одного метода и больше он использоваться не будет. сохранять ссылку на такой объект просто нет необходимости, так как она в дальнейшем не понадобиться.  с ActionListener - это реализация анонимного класса, причины его создания те же, что и выше, но требуется ещё переопределить какие то его методы.

Comment: Эта конструкция называет "Анонимный класс" - служил для того, чтобы не плодить ненужные переменные

Answer (score 1):

Да, вы правильно поняли.  Еще есть статические методы, они используются вот так: `ИмяКласса.имяМетода()`. Пример: `Math.abs();`.

`new A` - это ссылка на класс `A`. `A a = new A` - это переменная `a` типа `A`(как `int`, только `A`) ссылается на класс `A`. Также это операция называется *создание объекта*.

Java - это Объектно Ориентированный яп, и в яве все состоит из объектов.

Если у вам еще что то непонятно - то пишите в комментарии под этот ответ, а то ваш вопрос охватывает достаточно большую тему и не очень понятно про что конкретно писать. А если ответ ответил на ваш вопрос, то примите его, нажав на стрелку вверх и галочку рядом с ним.

Примеры: `method add(Class name) {...}`. Когда вы вызываете `add(new Class)`, вы ссылке name присваиваете значение `new Class`.

Или `ArrayList<Class> list ...;` `list.add(new Class);` - "переменной" в листе под номером 0 присваивается объект new Class. А `list.get(0)` - это ссылка на объект `new Class`.

Comment: A a = new A называется создание объекта. А вот когда используют конструкцию new A и всё, это как называется и зачем?

Comment: @MikeMclaren `new A` это ссылка на объект. `A a = new A` мы присваиваем переменной `а` ссылку на объект, `new A` - это и есть эта ссылка на объект `A`. С помощью ссылки вы можете получить методы из объекта - `new A.method()`. Если вам будет проще - то вот аналогия: как мы можем получить по ссылке на сайт информацию с сайта, так мы можем получить по ссылке на объект методы из объекта.

Comment: Всё ровно не понял, A abc = new A, я думал abc это и есть ссылка

Comment: @MikeMclaren нет `abc` - переменная. Опять аналогия: `int i = 33;` `i` - это переменная, тут происходит похожий процесс: присваивание переменной значения. Вы можете написать `Integer i = new Integer(33);` - это будет тоже самое. Кстати да, я наверное допустил ошибку - `new A` это не ссылка, это объект. Но когда мы пишем так: `A a = new A` мы присваием переменной `а` ссылку на объект `А`.

Comment: @MikeMclaren ну что, разобрались?

Comment: @MikeMclaren если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, то примите его, нажав на стрелку вверх и галочку рядом с ним.

Comment: Если мы в параметры передаем new ClassName, что мы должны туда положить получается?

Comment: @MikeMclaren куда положить и зачем?

Comment: Вижу в примерах когда в скобки передают new ClassName и не понимаю как это работает

Comment: @MikeMclaren передают новый объект. Я дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Метод `addActionListener()` принимает в качестве параметра класс. Вот мы и передаем вновь созданный объект и заодно переопределяем один из методов.